# How to freeze BN stats in PyTorch Quantization Aware Training when using FX graph mode

Tags: python, pytorch, quantization, quantization-aware-training

Freezing BN stats when doing Quantization Aware Training is a common training technique as introduced in Google Quantization Whitepaper. And [PyTorch official tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/static_quantization_tutorial.html#quantization-aware-training)'s code snippet also shows that how to do it in PyTorch:

```py
num_train_batches = 20

# QAT takes time and one needs to train over a few epochs.
# Train and check accuracy after each epoch
for nepoch in range(8):
    train_one_epoch(qat_model, criterion, optimizer, data_loader, torch.device('cpu'), num_train_batches)
    if nepoch > 3:
        # Freeze quantizer parameters
        qat_model.apply(torch.quantization.disable_observer)
    if nepoch > 2:
        # Freeze batch norm mean and variance estimates
        qat_model.apply(torch.nn.intrinsic.qat.freeze_bn_stats)

    # Check the accuracy after each epoch
    quantized_model = torch.quantization.convert(qat_model.eval(), inplace=False)
    quantized_model.eval()
    top1, top5 = evaluate(quantized_model,criterion, data_loader_test, neval_batches=num_eval_batches)
    print('Epoch %d :Evaluation accuracy on %d images, %2.2f'%(nepoch, num_eval_batches * eval_batch_size, top1.avg))
```

However, as its title indicates, this is code snippet for "eager mode". But i am trying to use the prototype FX Graph mode to do quantization aware training. The PyTorch official tutorial just shows that how to do PTQ when using FX Graph mode, only briefly introduce QAT in FX Graph mode.

```
#
# quantization aware training for static quantization
#

model_to_quantize = copy.deepcopy(model_fp)
qconfig_dict = {"": torch.quantization.get_default_qat_qconfig('qnnpack')}
model_to_quantize.train()
# prepare
model_prepared = quantize_fx.prepare_qat_fx(model_to_quantize, qconfig_dict)
# training loop (not shown)
# quantize
model_quantized = quantize_fx.convert_fx(model_prepared)

#
# fusion
#
model_to_quantize = copy.deepcopy(model_fp)
model_fused = quantize_fx.fuse_fx(model_to_quantize)
```

As the code snippet above shows, it simply omit the "training loop". What i wonder is, is the API to freeze BN stats in eager mode(`torch.nn.intrinsic.qat.freeze_bn_stats`) still available in FX Graph mode, which means i can use `model_prepared_fx.apply(torch.nn.intrinsic.qat.freeze_bn_stats)`) to achieve my goal? Or should i use another mechanism to do it?